# implementing MultiThread on GUI in windows form

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, multiprocessing

I have a project that contains some forms, class and Method. Some methods have a lot of process and I do threading on method, which works OK.
So, how can I do Multi threading or Parallel Processing on GUI of my forms?
I do this because when method being running as a GUI (like forms and another control) it is slow.
I wrote this code in Program class but have problems:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


            Parallel.Do(
              delegate()
              {
                  job();
              }
              );
        }

        public delegate void mydelegate();


        private static void job()
        {
            try
            {
                Application.Run(new frmMain());
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How can I speed this up using multi threading or parallel processing?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `Task` Class.

```
// Declare Task Object.
Task t = new Task(Job);
//Start another Task to do the job.
t.Start()
(...)
// Task ended
t.ContinueWith(task => 
 (.. process result if there is any ..)
);
```